# What's the hardness of a humanoid's skin?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

So as there are many things within the world that have a hardness, such as wood, steel and so on. What would the hardness of skin be? Bone is already given with the subject of special materials.

Rationale (probably unneeded):

> With the acceptance of my DM, I've been allowed to use Gloves of Shaping as a torture device of sorts. Whether or not that's ethical...well I'll leave that up to you to decide. But it is a question I've had before, since it's something I've wanted to know not only revolving around me being able to use Gloves of Shaping on an Elf's face.

Answer (score 4):

The [Hardness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/damaging-objects#TOC-Hardness) section calls out leather or hide as having a hardness of 2. Leather is toughened skin, so skin can't have a hardness of more than 2. Therefore, the rationale part of your question's answer is: "yes, [Gloves of Shaping](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-of-shaping) can shape a humanoid's skin (or, at least, they aren't prevented from doing so by hardness; as written, they probably shouldn't as they are specified to "shape objects", and creatures aren't objects)".

Rope has hardness 0 and glass has hardness 1. It's definitely easier to cut skin than glass (and, I'd argue, rope): think paper cuts. Therefore, human skin by itself should probably have hardness 0.

Comment: One might generalize that usefully to a hardness equal to its natural armor bonus, to accommodate this question on various victims.